# How to fetch multiple data appended to a URL using regexjs

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is the url:

```
http://url?query=orderform&sid=000&layout=&clientName=Client%20Demo%20TestprojectName=xxxxx
```

From  the above URL I want to fetch the clientName and projectName values and use it in my service. I am currently
using the below code in javacript:

```
testjs
{
    var clientName= getParam("clientName");
    var projectName = getParam("projectName");
    function getParam(name)
    { 
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]"); 
        var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)"; 
        var regex = new RegExp( regexS ); 
        var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
        if (results == null)
            return ""; 
        else 
            return results[1];
    }
}
```

The output of the above code is:

```
projectName=ModifiedProject
clientName=Client%20Demo%20TestprojectName=xxxxx
```

What changes shall I make to my getParam function so that if fetches the clientName as

```
Client%20Demo%20Test` and not `Client%20Demo%20TestprojectName=xxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clientName=((?:(?!projectName).)*)|projectName=([^&#]*)
```

Try this.Can be done using just one regex.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/28

```
var re = /clientName=((?:(?!projectName).)*)|projectName=([^&#]*)/gm;
var str = 'http://url?query=orderform&sid=000&layout=&clientName=Client%20Demo%20TestprojectName=xxxxx';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the client name you need to use a different regex with potive look ahead assertion as

```
clientName=.*(?=projectName)
```

will match `clientName=Client%20Demo%20Test`

For example : http://regex101.com/r/sW6jE7/2